# Run function from setInterval once

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a `setInterval` function which is calculating the difference between a certain date and the current time. When this difference reaches less than an hour, I want to run some code that should only be executed once.

```js
const countdownDate = new Date('March 15, 2021 11:30:00').getTime();
const HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS = 3600000;

let ticker = setInterval(() => {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let duration = countdownDate - now;
    
    if (duration < HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS) {
        console.log('This will keep running');
    }
    
    if (duration === 0) {
        clearInterval(ticker);
    }
}, 1000);
```

One method I've found to achieve this is by setting a global flag that is flipped once the function has run once.

```js
let bar = false;

function foo() {
   if (!bar) {
       console.log('This will only run once');
   }
   bar = true;
}

let ticker = setInterval(() => {

    if (duration < HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS) {
        foo();
    }

}, 1000);
```

Another way that works is to fire a custom event and register a one-off event handler. However i'm not sure if firing an event every second is less performant than the previous solution.

```js
const foo = new Event('foo');

document.addEventListener('foo', () => {
    console.log('This will only run once');
}, { once: true });

let ticker = setInterval(() => {

    if (duration < HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS) {
        document.dispatchEvent(foo);
    }

}, 1000);
```

I'm assuming there must be a better way to achieve the desired behaviour. I understand that it's not best practice to try run something only once inside a `setInterval` but i've not been able to find any other workarounds so far.

Comment: i think you can use recursive function with settimout inside it and passing  flag as permeters

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive function

```js
  const start = (stop ,under)=>{
   let underHour = under;
   const countdownDate = new Date('March 15, 2021 11:30:00').getTime();
   const HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS = 3600000;  
      if(!stop){
      setTimeout(function(){
                let now = new Date().getTime();
                let duration = countdownDate - now;
                if (!underHour) {
                  if (duration < HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS) {
                    console.log('This will keep running');
                    underHour = true;
                  }
                }
    
                start(duration === 0, underHour);
            
       },1000)
    }
} 
 
//-----------
start()
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to `setInterval`, thank you. However in the example you've provided, the code will keep running until the duration reaches 0. I'm looking to only execute some code a single time once the duration has elapsed under an hour, I should've mentioned that I also require the interval to keep going after this point too.

Comment: you can  pass to permeters to function  one  for stop and one run code before call the function i will edit my code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the `under` parameter is doing, would that be a boolean value that you pass in when calling `start()`? Because in my case, the duration is being calculated dynamically so you wouldn't be able to know when the duration has gone below an hour in advance. This was the other issue I was coming across, in terms of readability. I feel like the one off event handler is much easier to understand and maintain

Comment: i  pass it as  a secound paramter to run another piece of code once and  keep  "start" function runing